# Get connection string for the MySQL database installed on Droplet via SSH

Tags: mysql, .net, .net-core, digital-ocean

I just installed MySQL Server on my Droplet on Digital Ocean, and I have successfully set it up. I can connect to my db from MySQL Workbench.

Now I need to get the connection string to MySQL Database for the use in my .NET Core application.

### Background

My Droplet is set up to use SSH and the MySql Server is enabled to use password for localhost.

Say my Droplet IP is 122.34.52.233:36, Username is groove, use SSH.

MySQL Server on the Droplet IP is 127.0.0.1:14430, Username is apiuser, Password is abcpwd

As you can see the difficulty here is: Workbench allows me to specify IP and ssh file to connect to my Droplet and then has place for database host/ip and password, whereas ConnectionString does not have place for the ssh file, IP address for the Droplet, it only has place(Data Source) to specify database IP.

Comment: Surely if you can connect from Workbench you have all the bit you need to feed to any other language C# or VB.NET included

Comment: hi @RiggsFolly Workbench allows me to specify ssh file to connect to my Droplet, whereas ConnectionString does not have place for the ssh file.